# What are the Graphics capabilities of i915 driver?

Tags: intel-graphics, i915

I would like to know if the i915 driver supports all the features of DirectFB. I don't know  whether this is the right way to ask what I have in my mind. When I look at the code, I find that it support just 'fill rectangle' and 'image blitting'. Is that all or does it support more? Please guide me.

Comment: If it helps anyone find out, here's Intel's full developer documentation for the drivers, creative commons no less: http://www.x.org/docs/intel/

Comment: Why don't you trust the code?

Comment: Why are you after DirectFB support?  Very few apps are actually going to use it, and unless you've got strange requirements it's not going to be faster than running in X anyway.

Comment: @StefanoPalazzo, just to let you know, it appears that Intel has removed the i915 docs, but this is still a good resource nonetheless.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking at the code, and finding support only for 'fill rectangle' and 'image blitting', then that's probably all that's supported. If you need help analysing the code, try asking one of the [DirectFB mailing lists](http://www.directfb.org/index.php?path=Development%2FMailing+Lists).